# JS: cannot read this.data() in jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm kinda new to JS so this may be pretty easy to solve.
I simply want to change interactive map elements' opacity and color when mouse enters element and change it back when it leaves.

So this is what I'm doing:

```
var paper = Raphael('map', '100%', '100%');

// map contents
var rect = paper.rect(3.5714281, 74.505051, 151.42857, 143.57143).attr({
    x: '3.5714281',
    y: '74.505051',
    fill: '#ffb380',
    stroke: '#ff6600',
    'stroke-width': '1',
    'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).transform("t6.9285719,8.1378246").data('id', 'rect');

var crcl = paper.path("m 472.14285,202.00504 a 72.5,72.5 0 1 1 -145,0 72.5,72.5 0 1 1 145,0 z").attr({
    fill: '#916f6f',
    stroke: '#6c5353',
    'stroke-width': '1',
    'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).transform("t6.9285719,8.1378246 t-245,-127.14286").data('id', 'crcl');

var objs = [];
objs.push(rect, crcl);

for (var i = objs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        objs[i].data('original-fill', objs[i].data('fill'));

        objs[i].mouseover(function(event) {
            damn = this.data('fill');
            this.stop(true, false).animate({
                    opacity: 0.7,
                    fill: 'white',
                },
                75);
        });

        objs[i].mouseout(function(event) {
            this.stop(true, false).animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    fill: this.data('original-fill'),
                },
                200);
        });
    };
```

But every time i move mouse out it sets to 'none' like *this.data('original-fill')* was unset. Though I can access *objs[i].data('original-fill')* outside *mouseover* and *mouseout*.

I'm using Raphaël JS library.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is `original-fill` a color value and is CSS something you're able to use in your project?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using javascript instead of using css :hover property? That would be MUCH simpler.

Comment: yeah, I already know how to do it with CSS but I still want to learn JS and I'm wondering what is wrong with THIS script :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CSS is in your arsenal for the project, it offers a `transition` property and a `:hover` attribute to animate styles over a length of time on mouseover events.  If CSS is something you're able to use, this can accomplish what you're outlining in your expected behavior (just replace `div` with a class on the elements you're looking to animate):

```
div {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #000;

    transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
} 

div:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

It's not a javascript solution, but is considerably more elegant if your hover needs are strictly style-related

Comment: **transition** is a new thingy to me and I find it handy, thank you a lot, I can use it. But still i wonder if I can do it with only JS, what is wrong with my script?

Comment: Regarding your code, did you ever set `objs[i].data('fill')`?  It looks like you're setting it to `objs[i].data('original-fill')` before adding it to your `data` object (at least from the code you have in your question).  You'll need to do something like `objs[i].data('fill', 'someValue')` before you can access it by name from Raphael's data function.

Comment: I use RaphaelJS so I created a shape with attribute `fill: 'some color'` so it's initialized with this **fill** value... okay, I updated the post with some more code

Comment: I'm actually just looking at RaphaelJS now (so I may be wrong about this), but the `data` object does not include attributes defined on shapes.  You need to add the a key-value pair for `fill` not only to the `attr` object, but to the `data` object as well if you want to use it there.

Comment: when I try to get it out of attributes like `objs[i].attr('original-fill', objs[i].attr('fill'));` it doesn't work for me too :(

Comment: Instead of making it a custom attribute, give this a try `objs[i].data('original-fill', objs[i].attr('fill'));`

Comment: for me this one doesn't work too, I tried it almost in the very beginning, messing around with both data and attr

Comment: Not sure if it may be your environment?  I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77qtnqgt/) out of your code swapping out `objs[i].data('original-fill', objs[i].data('fill'));` with `objs[i].data('original-fill', objs[i].attr('fill'));` and it appears to work as expected

Comment: well... I guess yes, but I just write code in Sublime and test it in browser. anyway, it works here and I have to find out what's wrong with my environment, heh. Thank you a lot